# Flyout ToolTip using UserControl with rounded corners

Tags: c#, devexpress, tooltip

I have C# WinFrom project.

I would like to use DevExpress Flyout Tooltip with UserControl as content with rounded corners.

I added ToolTipController to form

```
this.toolTipController1.Rounded = true;
this.toolTipController1.RoundRadius = 15;
this.toolTipController1.ShowShadow = false;
this.toolTipController1.ToolTipLocation = DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipLocation.TopCenter;
this.toolTipController1.ToolTipType = DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipType.Flyout;
this.toolTipController1.GetActiveObjectInfo += new DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventHandler(this.toolTipController1_GetActiveObjectInfo);
this.toolTipController1.BeforeShow += new DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerBeforeShowEventHandler(this.toolTipController1_BeforeShow);
```

In `GetActiveObjectInfo` I set User Control as ToolTip content:

```
private void toolTipController1_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{         
    e.Info = new ToolTipControlInfo();
    e.Info.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    e.Info.Object = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    UCTest ToolTipUserControl = new UCTest();
    e.Info.FlyoutControl = ToolTipUserControl; 
}
```

According to tip that I found in Internet I added BeforeShow event to set rounded corners:

```
private void toolTipController1_BeforeShow(object sender, ToolTipControllerShowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Rounded = true;
    e.RoundRadius = 10;
}
```

Unfortunetly - this not working.
Corners are still square.

I tried changed it by modify UserControl.
I added:

```
private int radius = 20;
[DefaultValue(20)]
public int Radius
{
    get { return radius; }
    set
    {
        radius = value;
        this.RecreateRegion();
    }
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn(int nLeftRect, int nTopRect,
    int nRightRect, int nBottomRect, int nWidthEllipse, int nHeightEllipse);

protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    this.RecreateRegion();
}

private void RecreateRegion()
{
    var bounds = ClientRectangle;

    this.Region = Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(bounds.Left, bounds.Top,
        bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom, Radius, radius));
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

UserControl corners are rounded, but tooltip has a square border:
[image: ToolTip]

**What I have to do?**

Best Regards

Tomasz

Comment: Hi if your referring to the control in green then I can see that the corners are rounded

Comment: Dong Li - green control is a user control - has a rounded corners. But tooltip corners are still square